# How do I get an XP computer to send files to its archive when connected on different a different router?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, routing, windows-xp, subnet

Good day folks.

I'm wondering if its possible for my portable ultrasound machine to send back its images to the central archive when its off in the wards doing scans. Here's the current setup - the archive (on a Windows Server 2008r2 x1000 NAS with 2 NICs) and scanners are on static IPs - 192.168.0.x/24

The scanners report home fine when they are all connected to the same router (192.168.14.254/24). Its not possible when the portable scanners are in connected to the ward router (192.168.23.254/24). I ask since other PCs with DHCP assigned IPs on 192.168.14.x/24 and 192.168.23.x/24 can talk to each other.

The main purpose would be reviewing images remotely on the fly instead of waiting for the machine to be brought back for review purpose. I guess changing the archive to the 192.168.14.x subnet amd portable scanner to 192.168.23.x/24 should work - just hoping to keep the scanners and archive on a separate subnet if possible.

I was toying with the idea of a VLAN, but i prefer not to meddle with the hospital routers. Is there a way to configure the Windows Server machine to do the routing?

I'm not terribly good at this, please do guide me. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Packets can be forwarded between routers on different subnets, that's the primary function of routers. Assuming it is permitted by network policy.

Propose the portable ultrasound thing and its benefits to your network administrators. Someone is responsible for connectivity and security, they can provide context on how your request could be accommodated. Figure out why they are unreachable, before trying something like moving the devices to the PC network.

One possible reason for being isolated: Windows XP and Server 2008 R2 are end of life. Without security updates, they should not be on *any* network.

Upgrade to a supported operating system. If the vendor does not accept this, complain very loudly that they have insecure and broken software. Replace it with a different system if necessary.

Then proceed with the mobile scanning project.